# How to use the future tenses

Tags: grammar

When I'm 25 years, I will have graduated from university and ....... for a job.

a) will look     b) be looking     c) will have looked      d) am going to look

(1) I think the sentence will be OK and understood without (FROM UNIVERSITY )

(2) It seems to me that both a & d are correct.

What do you think.

Comment: Either ***When I'm 25*** or (rarely) ***When I'm 25 years old***, never ***When I'm 25 years.*** All 4 of your suggestions are syntactically valid, but they mean different things. What are you trying to express by your selected text in this example case?

Comment: When you reach 25 you will have graduated and: A= you probably intend to start looking; B= you will be in the continuous act of looking; C= you began looking at some point in the past and are still engaged in that search ; D = you definitely intend to start looking

Answer (score 0):

1. yes "from university" can be omitted.

a) is correct.  You can omit the middle bit and it still makes sense

> When I'm 25 <s>years</s>, I ... will look for a job.

b) is fine too

> When I'm 25, I will ... be looking for a job.

Notice this picks up the "will" from the first phrase.

There is a nuanced difference between the future simple and future continuous.

c) is grammatical but unusual. It says that the job hunt will be in the past when you reach 25.

> When I'm 25, I ... will have looked for a job.

d) doesn't work

> When I'm 25, I ... am looking for a job.

The time phrase is in the far future, but the verb is present continuous. It is syntactically valid, but the tense doesn't really fit the time phrase.

So a) or b) are most likely possible.  I'd probably choose "b" since that tells the most interesting story.  I want to know what you think you'll be doing when you are 25.